# Windows Phone application deactivation detection on Page

Tags: windows-phone-8, tombstoning

I am working on Windows Phone. When My application deactivated and goes into the background, I want to detect the application deactivation on OnNavigatedFrom event so that I can implement some logic if application goes into the background. How can I do this?????

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution myself. Attach handler to PhoneApplicationService.Current.Deactivated event on page from which you are navigated.

Answer (score 1):

You can Save the time wehn it deactivates from APP Events or page events and store that in IsolatedStorage then retrieve data wen your app reactivated ( OnNavigatedTo).

Answer (score 0):

Use the following methods (found in the App.xaml.cs file) to execute logic when the app is activated or deactivated:

```
// Code to execute when the application is launching (eg, from Start)
// This code will not execute when the application is reactivated
private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
{

}

// Code to execute when the application is activated (brought to foreground)
// This code will not execute when the application is first launched
private void Application_Activated(object sender, ActivatedEventArgs e)
{

}

// Code to execute when the application is deactivated (sent to background)
// This code will not execute when the application is closing
private void Application_Deactivated(object sender, DeactivatedEventArgs e)
{

}

// Code to execute when the application is closing (eg, user hit Back)
// This code will not execute when the application is deactivated
private void Application_Closing(object sender, ClosingEventArgs e)
{

}
```